# wxpython download progress bar laggy

Tags: wxpython, multiprocessing

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Y4dEsXge) is the code for a progressbar for a urlretrieve download in wx. I do the download work in a different process. It works, but is a bit laggy and unresponsive. As in I cannot move the window around freely. What could be the problem?

Comment: I am usually told not to use threads nor processes. People always point me to twister and event-driven programming (registering callbacks etc.) Threads and processes are a pain to debug and may have different behaviors on different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you're calling this:

```
self.dloader.parent_conn.recv()
```

That is probably a long running process, so it blocks wxPython's main loop, which makes the UI unresponsive. The typical workaround is to send a message back to the UI from the process or thread telling it to update. You will probably need to use one of wxPython's thread-safe methods to be safe:

- wx.CallAfter
- wx.CallLater
- wx.PostEvent

The canonical article on this topic can be found in the wxPython wiki:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

There is also a wiki page on MultiProcessing that you might find helpful:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiProcessing